# JavaScript Function Insertion Sorting/ Function undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am attempting to write a javascript file that has a insertion sort function, a function to check a sorted array and return true or false, and an insertion sort function that works from the end of the array index to the beginning. 
Here is the code i have

```
function insertionSort(arr) { 
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        var val = arr[i]; var j; for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > val; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1]; } arr[j] = val; }
    }
function reverseInsertionSort(arr) { 
    for(var i = arr.length; i >1; i--) 
    { var val = arr[i]; var j;
        for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > val; j--)
            { arr[j] = arr[j-1]; } arr[j] = val;
            } }
var length = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var arr = new Array();
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1);
}
console.log(arr);
//function sortCheck(arr) {
//for( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
//  if(arr[i]>rr[i+1]){
//      return false
//  }
//}
//return true}


var sortedArr = insertionSort(arr);
console.log(sortedArr);
console.log("And with reverse \n");
var reverseSortedArr = reverseInsertionSort(arr);
console.log(reverseSortedArr);
//console.log(sortCheck(sortedArr));
```

The issue I am having right now is that sortedArr is undefined when output with console.log, it appears that the issue is that my function is "undefined" but seeing how i define it above, i dont understand how that is.

Comment: Your functions have no return statements.

Comment: The formatting in this code makes my brain hurt. Why do you have multiple statements piled up in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insertionSort function doesn't return a value, it modifies the array passed as an argument. Instead of `var sortedArr = insertionSort(arr)`, just call `insertionSort(arr)` and then do `console.log(arr)`.

Comment: thank you! its been a while since i've used javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to return arr from the function. It is not returning anything that's why you are getting undefined

```js
function insertionSort(arr) { 
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        var val = arr[i]; var j; for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > val; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1]; } arr[j] = val; }
   return arr; }
function reverseInsertionSort(arr) { 
    for(var i = arr.length; i >1; i--) 
    { var val = arr[i]; var j;
        for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > val; j--)
            { arr[j] = arr[j-1]; } arr[j] = val;
            } return arr}
var length = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var arr = new Array();
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1);
}
console.log(arr);



var sortedArr = insertionSort(arr);
console.log(sortedArr);
console.log("And with reverse \n");
var reverseSortedArr = reverseInsertionSort(arr);
console.log(reverseSortedArr);
//console.log(sortCheck(sortedArr));
```

Comment: It's considered a bad practice to modify an array _and_ return it. You should either return a new array without modifying the argument, or modify the argument. Not both - this can cause nasty side effects.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), and [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) would suggest otherwise. That's nonsense. Document behavior and return the reference if you want, it's useful for chaining and other common language patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you return the array from the function(s). Since you currently are not, assigning the function to a variable would not yield any particular value.

```
function insertionSort(arr) { 
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        var val = arr[i]; 
        var j; 
        for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > val; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1]; 
        } 
        arr[j] = val; 
     } 
    return arr
}
```